# Definition of "crimp"

Tags: word-usage

Today is the first time I have come to face the word "crimp"
The dictionary says (among other things) * to pinch or press together (something, such as the margins of a pie crust) in order to seal*
[Dictionary definition](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/crimp)
Alright, I get it, a pie crust. How about if I seal a plastic package with a hot press? Is "crimp" there correct? How about a device that does this? A "crimp seal component"? (or maybe "crimping seal component?)

Comment: Could you add a dictionary link? Other definitions didn't help? For your hot press, "seal" is probably better. See [Ziploc® Brand Storage Bags ](https://ziploc.com/en/products/bags/storage/storage-bags-quart-medium) - "Smart Zip Plus® **seal**".

Comment: In the [Wikipedia entry for crimp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crimp_(joining)), it says, "Crimping is joining two or more pieces of metal or other ductile material by deforming one or both of them to hold the other. The bend or deformity is called the crimp."  That certainly matches my feeling of the word. A pie crust is _crimped_ not just because it's pressed together, but because it's also bent into a scalloped shape.  Without that bending process, it hasn't been crimped. The plastic package isn't bent, so it isn't crimped.

Comment: @CanadianYankee Thanks for the clear comment. It has helped me a lot

Answer (score 2):

A *crimp* is usually a joint where the mechanical strength of the material holds the joint together.

Here's a type I use pretty often at work:
[image]

The metal has been deformed so that it holds on to the wire end.

Heat-sealed plastic would not be considered a crimp, because it's not just a mechanical pressure that made the joint. Instead, heating the plastic has melted the two parts together and allowed chemical bonds to form between them.